# Why does Java add backslashes to my XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I copy an element's XPath and then paste it into my Java IDE (IntelliJ), backslashes are added to the XPath - why is this?

For example, IntelliJ automatically changes

```
//*[@id="SearchForm:FirstName"]
```

to

```
//*[@id=\"SearchForm:FirstName\"]"
```

Comment: It is escaping the quotes in the string

Comment: Please clarify where you're copying the XPath *from*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Java per se but your IDE that's doing this for you, because otherwise

- `"//*[@id="SearchForm:FirstName"]"`

would be interpreted as

- `"//*[@id="` [*junk after end of string resulting in a syntax error*]

So it escapes the embedded quotes for you:

- `"//*[@id=\"SearchForm:FirstName\"]"`

If you don't like this, you can **use single quotes**:

- `"//*[@id='SearchForm:FirstName']"`